# Check String length in XML tags - regex

Tags: java, regex, xml

I would like to check string length between XML tags using regex. The value of the string will always be 6 and I want to check that is 6.
I tried do it this way:

```
<tag>(.+?){6,6}</tag>
```

but it is always true, even if I change numbers. 
`(?=^.{6}$)` this regex also does not work, I get an error that regex does not contain. 
How is it possible to check length of string between tags?

I do not validate xml this way, I only want to check assertion.

Comment: You quantified a quantified subpattern. Use `<tag>.{6}</tag>` or `<tag>[^<]{6}</tag>`.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** You should not validate XML this way! Getting it right may become a very complex task.

Instead, **use an XML parser**, get the text value of the "tag" element, and checks its length.

But if you still want to do it this way, the following regex will do what you describe (but perhaps not what you want!):

```
<tag>.{6}</tag>
```

Why doesn't do it what you want?

1. Because this would also accept the following unwanted value:

   `<tag><foo/></tag>`
2. And it would not accept the following perfectly valid value:

   `<tag>foo&amp;ba</tag>`

   (That is, "tag" contains the 6-character text "foo&ba".)
3. But it would accept the following unwanted value:

   `<tag>2&gt;1</tag>`

   (That is, "tag" contains the 3-character text "2>1".)

To write a regex that solves all these issues is very complex and error prone. As written above, use a real XML parser instead.

But if you can live with a regex that is too strict (i.e. safely rejects all invalid values, but also rejects some valid values), **and you know for sure your XML file will be UTF-8 encoded**, then you can use:

```
<tag>[^&<]{6}</tag>
```

That is, 6 characters none of which are `&` or `<`.

(You could also exclude `>` just to "be sure", but this is not actually needed here, as `>` is a perfectly valid character within an XML string as long as it isn't part of a tag, i.e. you control all opening `<` characters, which you do in this case.)

If you know the exact set of allowed characters, things are simpler, you can also use that. For example, if exactly 6 uppercase letters are allowed, you may use:

```
<tag>[A-Z]{6}</tag>
```

Note that this regex is still too strict, as it disallowed for example the following perfectly valid input:

```
<tag  >[A-Z]{6}</tag>
```

Comment: I do not validate, I want to check assertion by this way.

Comment: You should have added that to your question. It changes the whole situation quite a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Easy and lengthy way to do it is to take the substring from >+1 and  <. But if the tags are wrong like texttag>, then it will throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException or if it is , then it will be tagtext!

First read the line as a string and then convert it to a character array and then iterate the line!
If the count of < & > is 2 for each, then take substring of from '> <'.

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
FileReader fr= new FileReader(path);

BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);

String str= null;

while((str=br.readLine())!=null)){ 
    list.add(str);
    }

//suppose you want to check 3rd line
int lbrack=0; rbrack=0;
String text= null;
String data= list.get(2);
char[] brack= data.toCharArray();
for(int i=0; i<brack.length;i++){
    if(brack[i]=='<')
    lbrack++;
    if(brack[i]=='>')
    rbrack++;
    }
if(lbrack==2 && rbrack==2){
      text= data.substr(data.indexOf(">")+1,data.indexOf("<"));
    }
else {
    System.out.println("this is root tag or some problem here");
}
```

Comment: It was asked for a solution using regex.